# Sequence of Mining and Collecting Transactions

Tags: transactions

I asked myself about the procedure of "Mining" and "collecting transactions". 
The way I understand it both processes are always active running parallel. So I assume a node has somehow two queues: one with the transactions of a block which they are currently mining and another one active collecting the transaction which will be part of the next block. So once a node found the nonce to a block it broadcasts the whole block. All nodes immediately start to mine a block containing the hash of the new (previous) block and the transactions (or a part) they were collecting while mining the previous block.

I already read [When does a miner decide to stop collecting transactions and start calculating hashes to try to win?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40398/when-does-a-miner-decide-to-stop-collecting-transactions-and-start-calculating-h?newreg=8956283180e04547b616dda39bda56be)
but like to have a confirmation of my understanding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a 'mempool' of unconfirmed transactions maintained uniquely by every node, ordered by fee-rate. Miners select a template based on these transactions that is most profitable for them. If they solve a block, or someone else solves a block, those confirmed transactions contained in the newly seen block are stubbed out of the mempool and a new template is formed from what's left.